# Injecting Custom Arguments to Default $post query Wordpress

Tags: post, arguments, parameter-passing, wordpress

Is there anyway, I can inject custom arguments into the default query that returns $post on archive pages?

E.g. On a Custom Archive I would do something like this:

```
<?php

    while(have_posts()): the_post();

    endwhile;

?>
```

So, how can I inject say 'orderBy' into that query so the $post objects follow that argument.

--

Is this even possible, or would it just be expected that I create and call a query myself?

Thank you.

Connor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also call via your custom query. but best solution is use below hook

```
    // Runs before the posts are fetched

    add_filter( 'pre_get_posts' , 'my_change_order' );
    // Function accepting current query

    function my_change_order( $query ) {
        // Check if the query is for an archive
        if($query->is_archive)
            // Query was for archive, then set order
            $query->set( 'order' , 'asc' );

**// for specific post type archive page only** 
$query->set( 'post_type', 'my_post_type' );

        // Return the query (else there's no more query, oops!)
        return $query;
    }
```

add above code in your function.php file

you can also pass your custom post type

```
$query->set( 'post_type', 'my_post_type' );
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_post_type_archive

```
<?php is_post_type_archive( $post_types ); ?>
```

Comment: Awesome! However, that will set the order for all queries globally right? I only really need to manipulate the order on one page of the website, so if for example I add a quick page id check, would this suffice in only altering the query arguments for that page? Thanks again!

Comment: you want it for your custom post type ?

Comment: Yes, I have a User's Custom Post type and I want them to be in a different order by default.

Comment: But only for that specific archive, I don't really want it to be a global query argument for all the instances of (have_posts()): the_post(); if that makes sense.

Comment: simple check my updated code. 

you need to use this in if condition 

$query->set( 'post_type', 'my_post_type' );